# Fail to push a standard Symfony PHP on Bluemix Cloud Foundry

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, symfony, buildpack

I'm unable to push a standard PHP Symfony application on Buemix Cloud Foundry, but the buildpack compilation step failed most likely due to this error:

[RuntimeException]
Could not scan for classes inside "app/AppKernel.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

Here are the 4 steps to reproduce:

1. I created a new project

   > composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition:^3.0 symfony_bluemix
2. I tested locally

   > php bin/console server:run
3. I added a manifest.yml file to the root of my project

   applications:

   ```
   - path: .
   memory: 256M
   instances: 1
   name: myphp-app
   host: myphp-app
   disk_quota: 1024M
   buildpack: php_buildpack
   ```
4. I push this project to Bluemix running

   > cf push

Anyone knows what needs to be configured to make it successful?

Answer (score 0):

Although I could not manage to make it working I know that these issue comes from the bluemix deployment when the symfony code is moved to the htdocs folder. In this case also the AppKernel has to be referenced by

> htdocs/app/AppKernel.php

in the composer.json